# If $T^2 = T$ and $T:V \to V$ , does it mean that $T$ is the identity transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Because if $T(v) = x$ then $T(x) = x$ so it must be the identity transformation ($T:V \to V)$. Right?

Comment: What about $T = 0$?

Comment: Then there are only 2 options?

Comment: The condition $T^2=T$ says that $T$ is a projection, there can be many projections.

Comment: No, the maps with this property are exactly the projections, and there is a projection for each choice of subspace $W \subset V$ and choice of complement of $W$ in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

No. take $T=0$ the zero linear map

Comment: So only 2 options?

Comment: No. Take $T$ sending $(x, y) \mapsto (x, 0)$.

Comment: So how can I find $[T]_E$ ($E$ is the standard basis) by only knowing that $T:V \to V$ and $T = T^2$ ?

Comment: @Joey02j You can't.

Comment: First of all you need more information on $T$ before you can find its matrix. Secondly, depending on which subspace you project, the standard basis may not be the easiest basis to find the matrix of the projection. You're much better off chosing a basis of the subspace in question and extending that one to a basis of all of $V$. Thirdly, if you're not working in finite dimensions, you cannot really talk about the matrix of a linear map. (Well you can in some sense, but that's not what you're asking here).